# Nested SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, ontology

I have the following structure an Object and each Object has multiple Children as Changelog to the Parent Object and each Change Log has an Author.
[image]

Now each Changelog has status and Timestamp I would now like to write a SPARQL query where I need to get the list of Objects which has me as the author and of particular status say "to be approved" and it has to be the latest changelog.

This query is what I have tried so far :
 I try to get first the changelog then the object related to it after that get all the other changelog in it and compare the latest changelog by timestamp and filter it if it is greater.

```
select ?Object WHERE{  ?author myPrefix:userId "myuserid".             
      ?changelog myPrefix:hasApprover ?author .
      ?changelog myPrefix:timestamp ?dv
      FILTER( ?dv >= ?latestdate )
       {
            SELECT (max(?dv1) AS ?latestdate) WHERE { 
               ?Object myPrefix:hasChangeLog ?changelog .
               ?Object  myPrefix:hasChangeLog ?changelog1 .
               ?changelog1 myPrefix:timestamp ?dv1 .                    
            }

        }
       ?changelog myPrefix:status "To be approved" .
       ?Object  myPrefix:hasChangeLog ?changelog .}
```

What I am doing wrong here is that it compares it to all the Objects changelog and not Objectwise comparison how can I achieve that?

Comment: you should show sample RDF data as well as what you tried so far.

Comment: Hi I have uploaded the query here not sure if I could post the data as it is confidential but can prepare some if needed

Comment: ok, not sure if I understand correctly, but shouldn't you just get the latest changelog per object then? Change the inner query to `SELECT ?Object (max(?dv1) AS ?latestdate) WHERE { 
               ?Object myPrefix:hasChangeLog ?changelog .
               ?Object  myPrefix:hasChangeLog ?changelog1 .
               ?changelog1 myPrefix:timestamp ?dv1 .                    
            } group by ?Object`

Comment: Whoops!!! that is what I was missing Thanx :)

Comment: Just another question the way I have done it is correct or there is a better way to write this same query?

Comment: no, I think this is the common way once you have to apply aggregates. The only thing that does confuse me is your redundant triple pattern in the subquery. What is the purpose of `?Object myPrefix:hasChangeLog ?changelog .` ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion from UninformedUser:

```
select ?Object WHERE{  ?author myPrefix:userId "myuserid".             
  ?changelog myPrefix:hasApprover ?author .
  ?changelog myPrefix:timestamp ?dv
  FILTER( ?dv >= ?latestdate )
   {
        SELECT (max(?dv1) AS ?latestdate) WHERE { 
           ?Object  myPrefix:hasChangeLog ?changelog1 .
           ?changelog1 myPrefix:timestamp ?dv1 .                    
        }group by ?Object

    }
   ?changelog myPrefix:status "To be approved" .
   ?Object  myPrefix:hasChangeLog ?changelog .}
```